# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE not working in Android Q Beta 2 Emulator?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-10.0

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, MY_RESULT_CODE);
```

Executing the above code does not open any file dialog in the emulator, is this a known bug?

Comment: FWIW, it works on a Pixel flashed with Q Beta 2 -- I tested using [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Documents/DocumentTree). Note that you do not need that `addFlags()` call.

Comment: this is terrible, support is urgently needed in emulator :(